# Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have stepped through my code to see if any nulls are present but everyone is bringing a value but I cannot find the issue.

```
public partial class UserDetail : ICSBaseUserControl
{
    UserRepository userDao = new UserRepository();
    User user;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            long userID = Convert.ToInt64(Request[UrlParameters.UrlParameterName.UserID]);
            user = (userID > 0) ? userDao.GetUser(AppSession.Company.ID, userID) : new c365_EntityFramework.User();
            if (user.ID > 0)
            {
                txtFirstName.Text = user.Forename;
                txtSurname.Text = user.Surname;
                txtAddress.Text = user.Address1;
                txtEmail.Text = user.Email;
                txtUsername.Text = user.Username;

            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool result = userDao.UpdateUser(user.ID, txtFirstName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtSurname.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtUsername.Text);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is how I fixed it, by moving `user` loading out of the `if(!IsPostBack)`:

```
public partial class UserDetail : ICSBaseUserControl
{
    UserRepository userDao = new UserRepository();
    User user;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long userID = Convert.ToInt64(Request[UrlParameters.UrlParameterName.UserID]);
        user = (userID > 0) ? userDao.GetUser(AppSession.Company.ID, userID) : new c365_EntityFramework.User();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (user.ID > 0) // Check for user ID
            {
                txtFirstName.Text = user.Forename;
                txtSurname.Text = user.Surname;
                txtAddress.Text = user.Address1;
                txtEmail.Text = user.Email;
                txtUsername.Text = user.Username;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line is the error on?

Comment: Where you are getting this error ?

Comment: bool result = userDao.UpdateUser(user.ID, txtFirstName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtSurname.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtUsername.Text);

Comment: I think its because the userID is passing as NULL.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is that the field `user` is not being instantiated and therefore will be `null` on your button click.

Your `Page_Load` only populates `user` if **NOT** a postback. So, when you press the button a postback is in progress and you are not getting the `user` at that point? Also, you need to look into the ASP .NET page life-cycle.

ASP .NET Pages do **NOT** remember fields and you may want to put the `user` into session state and then use it that way.

Comment: What have you tried / done when you say no it didn't work? Storing it in session? Recalling it? What? Show your updated code in new question or as an edit.

Comment: it didnt work properly

Comment: your answer wasnt correct

Comment: Care to enlighten us then?

Comment: sorted now i fixed it myself

Comment: @user2520671 - The polite thing to do would be explain how, why etc. SO is all about sharing knowledge. Other people may have the same problem. So why don't you list what you did to fix the issue so it can help others, we are a community!

Comment: @user2520671 You can post your solution as an answer to your own question. That way others who run into similar problems later know how to resolve it.

Comment: Edited my code to working solution

Comment: @user2520671 - You should not change your question but have added and **Edit** section underneath your original question or added it as an answer - I have done this for you. Also, my answer **DID** work!! I stated that it wasn't working because you had all your code in `if (!IsPostBack)` and would therefore not work on a postback. What you have done is move some of your code out of the if statement as I had told you! So I fail to see how you are saying my answer did not work?!